# too many redirects - Nginx redirect loop

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-config

Can anyone see why this configuration is ending in a redirect loop?  I know many people have posted similar questions and I have gone through dozens of them.  I can see where all of their configurations are going wrong but I can't for the life of me see a problem with mine.  If I go to the .well-known folder it works correctly.  Before anyone mentions cache issues, I have cleared browsers caches and server caches.  I have tried multiple browsers.  Any other ideas what is wrong?

******.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name www.*******.site ******.site;
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
default_type "text/plain";
root /var/www/******.com;
}
location / {
return 301 https://www.******.site$request_uri;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name www.******.site ******.site;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*******.site/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/******.site/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/******.site/chain.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

root /var/www/******.com;
index index.html index.php;

location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }
}
```

options-ssl-nginx.conf

```
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
```

redirect path

```
Status Code URL IP  Page Type   Redirect Type   Redirect URL    
301 http://www.*******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
301 http://www.******.site/ 172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   https://www.******.site/
301 https://www.******.site/    172.67.161.149  server_redirect permanent   http://www.******.site/
```

Comment: Can you share a sample curl request? What is the value of the location header? Did you stuck in a redirect even if you calling  a static file like index.hmtl or create a test.html file and try to get this one.

Comment: the only file in the folder at this stages is the nginx default html file

Comment: I've added the redirect path and as you can see it is redirecting back to http from https but I can't understand why or where this is coming from.

Comment: Look at the access log to check if this server is generating the 301 responses. If it is, use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included file.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for that I didn't know about the T switch.

Comment: @RichardSmith can you put that into an answer as it was exactly what I needed to work out what was going on and I want to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Richard Smith's comment, if you utilize the -T switch you can see all of the various configuration files which will help you track down where things are going wrong.